# GWT remote debug in IntelliJ: No connection to debug server

Tags: debugging, gwt, intellij-idea

I'm trying to configure my machine for remote GWT debugging.

In IntelliJ, I'm running with the following "Dev Mode" parameters:

```
-noserver -logLevel DEBUG -bindAddress 0.0.0.0 --startupUrl http://remote-server:8080/foo/foobar
```

I've also added the GWT module to load (tried both with 'All' and the specific module).

Netstat shows up that it is listening just fine on port 9997, and I can connect to the debug server if I write `http://127.0.0.1:9997` directly in the browser's address bar.

Anyways: I never get the message `Connection received from 127.0.0.1:.....` in the debug window, when I'm running the application in debug mode. (I got `?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`) at the end of the URL. (Like `http://remote-server:8080/foo/foobar?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`)

Does anybody have a clue on what's wrong with my setup?

Thanks in advance.

~Morten :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the browser plugin.

Seems like the browser just won't connect to the debug proxy if the plugin in absent.